# placing a div next two divs above each other

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to place the 3 divs as shown in the photo
**div number 2 must stick to the bottom**

here is what i have done:
http://jsfiddle.net/GLHur/1/

Comment: As my CSS skills are absolutely rubbish, I'm not going to post this as an answer. I'm going to post this as how not to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/GLHur/4/ Still works though!

Comment: @rsplak  your answer is right,but op mentioned in comment that he dont want to use fixed margins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
    #div3{height:100px;width:100px;border: solid 1px #000;
display:inline-block;}
    #div1{height:30px;width:100px;border: solid 1px #000;}
#div2{height:20px;width:100px;border: solid 1px #000; position: absolute; bottom: 0}
#div1_2{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top; position: relative; height: 100px;}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GLHur/18/

```
<div class="con">
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div1_2">
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

#div3{height:100px;width:100px;border: solid 1px #000; display:inline-block; background:red;}

#div1{height:30px;width:100px;border: solid 1px #000; position:absolute; top:0; background:blue;}
#div2{height:20px;width:100px;border: solid 1px #000; position:absolute; bottom:0; background:green;}

#div1_2{display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}


.con { position:relative; }​
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/GLHur/6/

---

Or does the height change once you add content?

Comment: div2's height sometimes differs thats why i cant use a fixed margin

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you tu use absolute position for this basic positionning :

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

.

```
#content { position: relative; height: 100px; width: 220px; }

#div1{ position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;   height:30px;  width:100px; background: blue; }
#div2{ position: absolute; bottom:0; right: 0; height:20px;  width:100px; background: green; }
#div3{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;    height:100px; width:100px; background: red; }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samsamX/GLHur/19/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="height: 100%;"> </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; right: 0px;"> </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"> </div>
</div>
```

By making the outer div 'relative' you can position the other divs inside using an absolute scale. Align the second one to the right, the last one to the right and the bottom. You might have to add height/min-height to the styles according to your needs.